# scala call tuple element with variable

Tags: scala

I'm new to scala and I'm trying to figure out how tuple works. I'm trying to call the xth element of a tuplle where x is a variable but it seems not to work, how should I do?

```
for (x <- 1 to 2; j <- 0 to (N-1)) yield((j, index._x), (x-1,index._x))
```

In particular the  `index._x` seem to not work

Comment: You can't do that, and is not the intended way of using tuples. Maybe you want a `Vector` instead.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to do this using the `Product` trait, though, as mentioned in the comment, this is not really a good idea or the intended way tuples are supposed to be used:

```
    val indexed = index.productIterator.toIndexedSeq
    for { 
      x <- 1 to 2
      j <- 0 until N
    } yield ((j, indexed(x-1)), (x-1, indexed(x-1))
```

or better yet (get rid of indexed access, it's yuky):

```
   index.productIterator.take(2).toSeq.zipWithIndex
     .flatMap { case (value, index) => 
         (0 until N).map { j => ((j, value), (index, value)) }
     }
```

I'll say it again though: there is about 99% chance there is a better way to do what you are actually trying to do. Tuples are meant for grouping data, not iterating over it (use collections for that).

Comment: The reason this is almost never a good idea is that you now no longer know the type of the field.